# Uninstalling and removing configuration of SelfControl app

Tags: software-uninstall

I installed this app and it made a mess. I haven't been able to visit the websites I blocked for 30min for days!

Does anybody know how to radically clean up this app and all the restrictions it has made? I want to eradicate it! :)

Comment: Please change your title to 'Uninstalling and removing configuration of SelfControl app'

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal window, and type `sudo apt-get purge <package-name>` and enter your user password when prompted.  This usage will remove all settings and data stored by the package application (as opposed to simply uninstalling as would occur with `sudo apt-get uninstall <package-name>`).

You will need to know the package name for the application; that should be available from the "installed packages" list in the package manager you use.